# Is it wrong to register a 3rd party container with IServiceCollection in AspnetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation, simple-injector

A little background: I began to incorporate `FluentValidation` in an AspnetCore application where I use `SimpleInjector` as my DI of choice. According to the aspnet docs

> "The ConfigureServices method typically returns void, but if its
>   signature is changed to return IServiceProvider, a different container
>   can be configured and returned"

This is all well a nice until I realized I needed to configure services that were not mine, which is why the example uses `containerBuilder.Populate(services);` i imagine. The nice thing about `FluentValidation`is I can created my own `IValidatorFactory` to resolve my validators (which is where my problem came from because my validators were registered with SimpleInjector, not the default container which thought I had none). I figured I could get around this headache by registering SimpleInjector's `container` with the `IServiceCollection` and inject that into my `IValidatorFactory` as the `IServiceProvider` instead of returning the container in the `ConfigureServices` method. Seems like it all works as a hack, but is this the way to go? Are there other ways besides the aspnet docs wiki?

**references**: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/ServiceProviderValidatorFactory.cs

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are fundamental incompatibilities between Simple Injector and the ASP.NET Core DI abstraction (i.e. incompatibilities that can't be solved) and many [problems in general](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) with the abstraction that Microsoft proposed.

Because of this [our official advice](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) is to:

> Refrain from using a self-developed or 3rd party provided adapter for the .NET Core DI abstraction. Isolate the registration of application components from the framework and 3rd party components. Pursue a SOLID way of working and allow your application registrations to be verified and diagnosed by Simple Injector, without concern for incompatibilities with the framework and 3rd party components.

You can read in detail [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) how you should work with ASP.NET Core when it comes to using a 3rd party container.

Comment: This is disappointing that you're taking a political stance, rather than a technical one on the issue.  You've always created opinionated software, but you've also always given us the tools to do the popular things you don't approve of.  This seems a departure from that traditional way of doing things, and frankly very disappointing.

Comment: thanks. I read that article the other day when I brought `SimpleInjector` into my project and created adapters for my code where necessary. I guess I missed the 3rd party part!

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Please take the time to inform yourself by reading the articles a referenced closely and the resources that are linked from those articles. After that you will realize that this is not a political stance, but in fact a technical one. Simple Injector can't comply for technical reasons to the world of the Comforming Container as Microsoft proposes it.

Comment: @Steven - You can't expect us to believe that.  That's like Microsoft saying they couldn't remove IE from Windows.  It's your software, you can do whatever you want with it.  You choose not to, however.  "Won't" is not the same as "can't"

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch this discussion is useless as long as you don't read the linked articles. In the articles I made it cristal clear why we can't conform.

Comment: @Steven - I've read them, and while i'm not intimately familiar with the internal workings of SI, it seems quite possible to write adapters and shims that would make interoperability possible.  For instance, your arguments about collection and open-generic registrations is silly.  You are creating a strawman argument and pretending it's technically impossible to do something you simply don't want to do.  You even allude to that with "violate the principles that underpin our vision".

Comment: @Steven - would those be more work?  Sure.  But they are possible.  I also don't agree that it's necessary to remove features to support a conforming container, or that this would stifle innovation.  It's just support a single use case, and all the rest of the features are still there should one want to take advantage of them.  I think there is a bit of a strawman argument in regards to "lowest common denominator", which says "Well, we have to throw away everything that makes us unique".  No, you do everything you currently do, you just add support for the container as well.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Until you fully understand what a [conforming container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) actually means, I think you should be careful with this kind of comments. There are several implicit behaviours which have to be met. All DI container have to change their own behavior in order to conform. So "you do everything you currently do" is completely out of the question if support for .Net Core is added. The product **will change**! And if you fail to understand why, I suggest you keep reading until you do and come back afterwards.

Comment: @Ric.Net - that's a huge strawman.  It's completely and totally wrong that a container that supports a conforming container can only support the conforming containers features.  That's a ridiculous claim by any stretch of the imagination, and I have argued with Seeman about this in the past.  There is nothing.. NOTHING.. that prevents you from implementing the conforming container requirements as well as implementing your own containers features.  There is nothing in the .NET DI spec that says you cannot do things their way in addition to your own way.

Comment: @Ric.Net - A conforming container is minimum set of functionality, not a maximum set.

Comment: @erikfunkenbusch you're suggesting to create a separate container that can conform to the abstraction. That's already there, it's the built-in container from asp.net core...

Comment: @Ric.Net - no, I'm suggesting that the container can conform to both, if you're willing to be pragmatic about it.  Most DI purists are not pragmatic, and they see the situation as binary.  DI purists argue generalities "Oh, it's likely to cause this, or leads to that".  There's a lack of concrete arguments other than how many angels can dance on a pinhead.  Seeman and others are happy to tell you what you're doing wrong, but refuse to tell you how to do things right.  The framework problem is a tricky one, and all DI Purists can do is veto solutions, not provide any themselves.

Comment: @Ric.Net - case in point, Seeman and others argued endlessly with the .NET team about this, but couldn't come up with any pragmatic solutions to the problems being addressed.  That is why the .NET team continued on their course.  Because nobody could state clearly, and matter of factly what they SHOULD be doing (other than not trying to solve the problem in the first place).

Comment: @Ric.Net - Here's an example of using a feature of AutoFac that's not defined by the container.  http://www.strathweb.com/2016/03/the-subtle-perils-of-controller-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-mvc/  - While it's "more work" to use the functionality, this could easily be wrapped up by an extension (just like so much functionality people need from SI already requires).  I'm not arguing that the .net DI abstraction is good or correct or that there's not room for improvement, but it's not the "lowest common denominator" situation that is being argued.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You seem to have some great ideas on how to make the adapter work for Simple Injector. Please send us a pull request so we we can discuss this and make it work.